# Creating a Searchable Database Website

Tags: database, web, searchable

Let me give some background before diving into my question. I am grad student and read a lot of research papers. Whenever I read a paper, I try to do a brief summary on it, etc. I am trying to come up with a way to maintain these summaries in a searchable list.

First off, let's go in what exactly is in each entry:

- Title
- Author List
- Publication Venue
- Date of Publication
- Keywords / Tags
- Summary
- Link to Paper

What I'd like is to create some type of website where I can add new entries in this format, and then search for matching entries. I've tried to maintain the list using a text document (garbage), Wiki Page (better, but not searchable). In particular, a document can have several keywords. So we can think that if there was a paper with the tags "machine learning" and "databases", and the data was organized via webpages with tags, that same entry would need to be on both web pages.

Ideally, I could search "machine learning" (a tag) and all publications with the tag "machine learning" would populate in a list. To be clear, for this list, I'd like the list that's being populated to be the **complete entry,** so I could read multiple entries on a single page. I **don't** want every entry to be it's own web page.

I've tried Googling around for this, but I haven't found any great solution to implement this. I have the ability to host my own site, so that wouldn't be an issue. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [Blogger](https://www.blogger.com) from Google, it meets all yours demands.